# Adding array to $_SESSION

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

I Have the following situation where I need add several values from `$usuario` to `$_SESSION`. Here's one way to do this however is cumbersome as `$user` has too many fields.

```
$_SESSION['logado_ecse']    = true; 
$_SESSION['user']           = $usuario['login'];
$_SESSION['usuario_id']     = $usuario['id'];
$_SESSION['habilitada']     = $usuario['habilitada'];
$_SESSION['bloqueada']      = $usuario['desbloqueada'];
$_SESSION['administrador']  = $usuario['administrador'];
                ....
$_SESSION['auditor']        = $usuario['auditor'];
```

I was looking for a more elegant solution where in just one line I could do the same as for example something like this, but this solution doesn't work as expected.

```
$_SESSION = array_merge($usuario, $_SESSION);
```

The variable $usuario is as follows

```
echo gettype($usuario);
array

var_dump($usuario);
array (size=34)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'login' => string 'admin' (length=5)
  1 => string 'admin' (length=5)
  'auditor' => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => string '0' (length=1)

              ...
  'telefone2' => string '11' (length=2)
  14 => string '11' (length=2)
```

I like @KV's solution, I think I'm gonna implement it as a function. So far, my idea is that `$_SESSION` is a container to "the user", so a solution such as

```
 $_SESSION['USER']=$usuario
```

will fragment the user's info in two

```
 $_SESSION['some_name']
 $_SESSION['USER']['some_name']
```

, not to mention that I'll have to reformat other parts of the code.

Comment: why not just `$_SESSION['USER']=$usuario;`

Answer (score 3):

You can push `$usuario` array onto `$_SESSION` array like this:

```
$_SESSION['user_details'] = $usuario;
```

And after that you can retrieve user details like this:

```
echo $_SESSION['user_details']['login'];
echo $_SESSION['user_details']['id'];
echo $_SESSION['user_details']['habilitada'];
...
echo $_SESSION['user_details']['auditor'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($usuario as $k => $user) if(is_string($k)) $_SESSION[$k] = $user;
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to add a description of what the code does instead of just providing section of code.

Comment: @XO Well, the code does what the OP is asking. One line of code to set the session vars.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$_SESSION['user'] => Array(
'userid'=> '123',
'username'=> 'some_joe',
'role' => 'customer',
'website' => 'http://www.example.com'
);

// reading values from array
$userid = $_SESSION['user']['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
// etc. etc.

// adding values to array
$_SESSION['user']['something'] = "Foo";
$_SESSION['user']['somethingelse'] = $bar;

// Adding via function
Set_Session('user', array('var'=> 'value'));

// determine if session has started
Function HasSessionStarted() {

    $result = false; // default to false

    // Check if session has started
    IF ((session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) || (session_id() == '')) { 
        $result = true; 
    }

    return $result;

}

// Set a session value
Function Set_Session($name, $value) {
    /* @params value: can be a string or an array */
    $new_session = HasSessionStarted(); // Check Session Status

    IF ((isset($name)) && (isset($value))) {
        IF ($new_session) { session_start(); }
        $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
        IF ($new_session) { session_write_close(); }
    }

}

Function Unset_Session($name) {

    $new_session = HasSessionStarted(); // Check Session Status

    IF (isset($_SESSION[$name])) {
        IF ($new_session) { session_start(); }
        unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        IF ($new_session) { session_write_close(); }
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

just assign $usuario to session variable:

$_SESSION['user'] = $usuario;